# How I can write the format of my date when I use apply and datetime functions?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to put days first on my datatime format. On other application I've used the following:

```
df2.Timestamp = pd.to_datetime(df2.Timestamp,dayfirst=True) #the format is d/m/yyyy
```

Now I want to use apply function, because I have more than one column and instead of doing it in 4 rows I wanted to do it in one row using apply.

```
df2[["Detection_time", "Device_ack", "Reset/Run", "Duration"]] = df2[["Detection_time", "Device_ack", "Reset/Run", "Duration"]].apply(pd.to_datetime)
```

But I don't know how to configure "dayfirst" argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
(df2[["Detection_time", "Device_ack", "Reset/Run", "Duration"]]
                           .apply(pd.to_datetime,dayfirst=True))
```

Comment: @Ipa Sure, dont forget to assign this back :)